# Toggle table with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm stuck getting a table to toggle.

This line of code given by W3school just won't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

This is the url: http://www.besteadministratiekantoren.nl/training/

Any thoughts on this one?

Many thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Stefan

Comment: jQuery('selector goes here').toggle()

Comment: Post your HTML you're applying this to, not a link to the site. Also, bring up your console, are there any errors?

Comment: `This line of code given by W3school just won't work.` I am *shocked*. http://w3fools.com

Comment: For once, `This line of code` actually seems correct. The jQuery global `$` is undefined, judging by the error in the console...

Answer (score 2):

Page is using `noConflict` which means `$` alias no longer exists for jQuery.

Two workarounds are:

Always write out `jQuery` instead of `$`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#flip").click(function(){
    jQuery("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Or wrap all new jQuery code in:

```
(function($){
   /* "$" is jQuery inside this wrapper*/
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
      });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of jQuery you are loading when you say

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.besteadministratiekantoren.nl/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
```

has been modified from the official jQuery script: you/they have added a `jQuery.noConflict()` call at the end. This call instructs jQuery to only operate under the name `jQuery` instead of under the name `$` (see [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)).

You can fix this by changing each use of `$` to `jQuery`. Or if you're satisfied that allowing jQuery to use the `$` global won't conflict with any other libraries, then remove the `jQuery.noConflict()` call, or load in a version of jQuery that doesn't end with a `jQuery.noConflict()` call (e.g. from [Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery), which is often a good thing to do anyway for reasons discussed [here](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/)).

Update: there is a third option too – wrap your jQuery blocks in a function that maps `jQuery` to `$`. See @charlietfl's answer.

Comment: suggesting loading another copy of jQuery isn't goood. Likely this is a CMS like Wordpress that due to huge number of plugins available that can be installed from admin uses `noConflict` for good reason

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine

http://jsbin.com/eCoReCE/1/

I assume your jQuery is launched in `` `hoConflict `` mode. Just change to

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
      $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```